# Create a nested array of objects from flat object array with childIds

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion, data-structures

I have a flat array of objects that I need in a (deeply) nested array of objects.

My flat array (IDs are random in reality, but changed here for clarity, and nesting can be very deep):

```
const tags = [
  {
    id: 'tag1',
    title: 'Tag 1',
    childIds: ['tag11', 'tag12'],
    root: true
  },
  {
    id: 'tag11',
    title: 'Tag 11',
    childIds: ['tag111', 'tag112'],
  },
  {
    id: 'tag12',
    title: 'Tag 12',
    childIds: ['tag121']
  },
  {
    id: 'tag111',
    title: 'Tag 111',
    childIds: []
  },
  {
    id: 'tag112',
    title: 'Tag 112',
    childIds: []
  },
  {
    id: 'tag121',
    title: 'Tag 121',
    childIds: []
  }
]
```

My desired output:

```
tagsNested = [
  {
    id: 'tag1',
    title: 'Tag 1',
    tags: [
      {
        id: 'tag11',
        title: 'tag 11',
        tags: [
          {
            id: 'tag111',
            title: 'Tag 111',
            tags: []
          },
          {
            id: 'tag112',
            title: 'Tag 112',
            tags: []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'tag12',
        title: 'tag 12',
        tags: [
          {
            id: 'tag121',
            title: 'Tag 121',
            tags: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

]
```

My best effort so far keeps nesting all tags under any tag.

**I.e. I do get a nested array, but each tags-array contains all tags**.

```
function unflatten(tag, nestedTags) {
  if (tag.childIds) {
    tag.childIds.forEach((childId) => {
      var childTag = tags.find((t) => t.id === childId)
      childTag.tags = unflatten(childTag, nestedTags)
      nestedTags.push(childTag)
    })
  }
  return nestedTags
}
const rootTag = tags.find((tag) => tag.root)
console.log(unflatten(rootTag, []))
```

I really struggle with these recursive functions and figuring out how to make the return statements give me the right data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a recursive approach. It works like that:

1. Given the `root` tag (or any tag) and `tagsArray` (flatten array of tags)
2. Filter all children tags of `root`
3. Then for each child find all its children tags
4. Then return the tag when there is no more children tags

You might try this code snippet:

```js
const tags = [
  {
    id: 'tag1',
    title: 'Tag 1',
    childIds: ['tag11', 'tag12'],
    root: true
  },
  {
    id: 'tag11',
    title: 'Tag 11',
    childIds: ['tag111', 'tag112'],
  },
  {
    id: 'tag12',
    title: 'Tag 12',
    childIds: ['tag121']
  },
  {
    id: 'tag111',
    title: 'Tag 111',
    childIds: []
  },
  {
    id: 'tag112',
    title: 'Tag 112',
    childIds: []
  },
  {
    id: 'tag121',
    title: 'Tag 121',
    childIds: []
  }
]

function buildTag({id, title, childIds}, tagsArray) {
  const tags = tagsArray
    .filter(tag => childIds.includes(tag.id))
    .map(tag => buildTag(tag, tagsArray))

  return {
      id,
      title,
      tags,
    }
}

const rootTag = tags.find((tag) => tag.root)
console.log([buildTag(rootTag, tags)])

/* 
tagsNested = [
  {
    id: 'tag1',
    title: 'Tag 1',
    tags: [
      {
        id: 'tag11',
        title: 'tag 11',
        tags: [
          {
            id: 'tag111',
            title: 'Tag 111',
            tags: []
          },
          {
            id: 'tag112',
            title: 'Tag 112',
            tags: []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 'tag12',
        title: 'tag 12',
        tags: [
          {
            id: 'tag121',
            title: 'Tag 121',
            tags: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
*/
```

Comment: This works, but is not efficient. It has a O(n²) time complexity, while it can be done with O(n) time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Map to key each node, and then make the new object format from that. Finally delete the entries from the map that have parents, so that the root remains. So really, the `root` property is not needed. It follows indirectly from the given relationships. This algorithm does not use that property:

```js
const tags = [{id: 'tag1',title: 'Tag 1',childIds: ['tag11', 'tag12'],root: true},{id: 'tag11',title: 'Tag 11',childIds: ['tag111', 'tag112'],},{id: 'tag12',title: 'Tag 12',childIds: ['tag121']},{id: 'tag111',title: 'Tag 111',childIds: []},{id: 'tag112',title: 'Tag 112',childIds: []},{id: 'tag121',title: 'Tag 121',childIds: []}];

let map = new Map(tags.map(({id, title, childIds}) => [id, { id, title, tags: [] }]));
tags.forEach(tag => map.get(tag.id).tags = tag.childIds.map(id => map.get(id)));
tags.forEach(tag => tag.childIds.forEach(id => map.delete(id)));
let tagsNested = [...map.values()];
console.log(tagsNested);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an iterative approach with an object as reference to the nodes.

```js
const tags = [{ id: 'tag1', title: 'Tag 1', childIds: ['tag11', 'tag12'], root: true }, { id: 'tag11', title: 'Tag 11', childIds: ['tag111', 'tag112'] }, { id: 'tag12', title: 'Tag 12', childIds: ['tag121'] }, { id: 'tag111', title: 'Tag 111', childIds: [] }, { id: 'tag112', title: 'Tag 112', childIds: [] }, { id: 'tag121', title: 'Tag 121', childIds: [] }],
    tree = function (array) {
        var t = {},
            tree = [];

        array.forEach(({ id, title, childIds, root }) => {
            Object.assign(
                t[id] = t[id] || {},
                { id, title, tags: childIds.map(id => t[id] = t[id] || { id }) }
            );
            if (root) tree.push(t[id]);
        });

        return tree;
    }(tags);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/green-dawn-3gpvz?file=/src/index.js. The only difference with your requirement is result is just an object not an array, but you can simply wrap this single element to be an array

```
function resolveChildren(tag, allTags) {
  const { childIds, root, ...rest } = tag;
  if (!childIds) return rest;

  return {
    ...rest,
    tags: childIds.map(childId =>
      resolveChildren(allTags.find(t => t.id === childId), allTags)
    )
  };
}

resolveChildren(tags.find(tag => !!tag.root), tags)
```

Comment: Please include code in your answers.  An external link is fine as well, especially if it can offer more context, but the relevant code should always be available here.